# react-markdown: Any plugin or ready solution for highlighting texts in html then store as markdown

Tags: markdown, highlight, react-markdown

In a React application I use [react-markdown](https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown) library to convert markdown string (received from API) to html. The following functionality also needs to be implemented:

> Let users highlight part of the text and mark them as correct or incorrect

The current solution stores the raw HTML string into the database and then `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` to render the HTML.

I'm pretty sure there should be a better approach for this problem. Ideally, I'd like a solution that lets me modify the original markdown string by adding ==highlight== syntax, and a way to store the user input data.